# JBoss Application Server 7.0.1 deploy with unexpected error

Tags: deployment, jboss7.x

Please help i cant get this to deploy. i've searched for it but no answer found as JBOSS AS7 is new. im trying to deploy war file into remote server.

```
SEVERE [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-9) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/virtual/VirtualFileVisitor
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/virtual/VirtualFileVisitor
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:348) [spring-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.virtual.VirtualFileVisitor from [Module "deployment.ProTurism.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
```

almost same error oer here. few seconds later

```
00:51:19,379 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ProTurism]] (MSC service thread 1-9) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/virtual/VirtualFileVisitor
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/virtual/VirtualFileVisitor
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:348) [spring-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.virtual.VirtualFileVisitor from [Module "deployment.ProTurism.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Spring really, but maybe I can at least point you in a direction that would help. [This](http://community.jboss.org/blogs/mariusb/2011/07/13/spring-and-jboss-as7-part-1-getting-started) blog post is a little old, but probably still relevant. There is also some information in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Spring+applications+development+and+migration+guide).

I know I've see some stuff written about Spring on JBoss AS7 on [community.jboss.org](http://community.jboss.org) too. You might want to poke around there and see what you can't find.